# How do I get an old iOS 4.1 iPhone 3GS to sync with my iCloud contacts on my OS X 10.7.5 Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, contacts

I have an iPhone 3GS that is unlocked and jailbroken. It is running iOS 4.1. I cannot update because that will undo the unlock mechanism.

I was originally on an iPhone 4S. It got bricked somehow, so I pulled out my old iPhone 3GS. I had already migrated completely to iCloud for my contacts; I run 10.7.5 on my Mac and was using iCloud to sync all of our Apple devices.

With iOS 4.1, it doesn't support iCloud, but I can't get it to sync my contacts manually. I was hoping that when I connected my iPhone to iTunes, that by clicking the 'Sync Contacts' under 'Info', it would just pick up all the iCloud contacts that are stored locally on my Mac and treat them as regular contacts.

Apparently it doesn't work this way. iTunes doesn't see iCloud contacts stored in the Address Book as normal contacts so those don't get synced.

Is there a way to get around this? I'm willing to do a manual sync (i.e. use some other app to copy, en masse, the contacts over), since my contact base doesn't change very frequently.

Comment: It used to work that way - since iCloud was fully established that page has become redundant. That phone can run iOS 6.1.6, which can be jailbroken. idk about whatever 'lock' you mean. If you mean network lock, that's beyond my experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the contacts/address book app on you mac, select all the contacts (either cmd-a or select first, scroll to bottom, hold shift and select last) and you can either right click or click on the little cog wheel at the bottom of the app and export the contacts to a vCard.

You can then use another free cloud service such as google or yahoo and import the contacts into that account on their website.

Sign in to this account on your iPhone and choose to use it for contacts only and they should start to all sync down from the cloud.